# SEQUELIZE refresh table data

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using the same MySQL database with a nodejs app backed by SEQUELIZE and with an another app.
If I am modifying a value by the third party application, the SEQUELIZE can not recognise the change, providing the same old value on select.

The question is: how can I refresh the data in every select query or in the connection options?

Answer (score 0):

> If I am modifying a value by the third party application

It can be if your third party application not commit SQL transactions. Check options like "Commit" or "Autocommit" etc.

Comment: Autocommit is set to 1.

Comment: What third party application do you use?

Comment: Apparently there are two. A PHP app with eloquent and a Flask based python one with peewee.